# add double Quotes only to one key value pairs using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
    coordinateid: [20,54.1],
    colorid: [250,0,0],
    sizeid: [2000],
    tooltipid: [B],
```

How to get this result, adding quotes to the value of tooltipid only, leaving everything else as it is, I am using regex in javascript

```
    coordinateid: [20,54.1],
    colorid: [250,0,0],
    sizeid: [2000],
    tooltipid: ['B'],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should match `tooltipid` in order to prevent adding quotes to other pairs.

This regex would do it: `/tooltipid: \[(.*)\]/gm`. And your replacement string should be `tooltipid: ['$1']`.

In JS the code would be: `"the text".replace(/tooltipid: \[(.*)\]/gm, "tooltipid: ['$1']")`

Here is the Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/itwoYw/1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to replace any value that's letters inside square brackets, replace `\[([a-zA-Z]+)\]` with `['$1']`, where $1 is your first capture group.

[image: regex diagram]

Alternatively, you could use lookarounds and replace `(?<=\[)([a-zA-Z]+)(?=])` with just `'$1'`